# plot 2D graph with points from a file

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have a file with values

```
2   2
3   21
4   583
5   197
6   83
7   179
8   246
9   220
10  393
11  295
12  339
13  250
14  223
15  194
16  895
17  201
18  1097
19  371
20  706
21  76
22  180
23  236
24  238
25  101
26  101
27  79
28  116
29  70
30  112
31  54
32  4849
33  53
34  53
35  50
36  32
37  53
38  67
39  35
40  126
```

and so on. I want to plot these points into a 2D graph.

Comment: OK, and what part is giving you trouble? I see you tagged with gnuplot, so should we assume you want to use that tool? What do you have so far? If you don't share what you've done with us, we'll just waste your time telling you things you've already tried. So please [edit] your question and explain what you have so far and what you need help with.

Comment: the data is generated using a tool. It gives output in this format. I tried using the tool '`plot`. Says these is an undefined symbol in the file.

Comment: Well, that's precisely the sort of information that should be in the question. Please ***[edit]*** your question and i) tell us what tool you used; ii) show how you imported the data into gnuplot; iii) show us the *exact* error message you got. We can't help you fix a problem if you don't tell us what the problem is. Could the data be coming from a Windows program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to paste numbers into a
file using an editor e.g.

```
  $ vi mynumbers.dat
```

and then start gnuplot and make a scatter plot

```
 $ gnuplot
 gnuplot> plot 'mynumbers.dat'
```

This will produce the following image

[image]

It seems like this question must already have an answer somewhere in SE
though?